# column's maxWidth is not resizable with autoAutoSize function in ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to apply `autosizecolumns` function with AG-Grid and angular framework. As the function act the column will take the content's width by default. Therefore I set a `maxWidth` for the column in case I have long content. The problem is the column's width will be restricted, it will not be resizable can not pull or expand the column more than maxWidth in case I want to see all the content in the cell.

[here](https://plnkr.co/edit/tmpmGeVATDe2YnxUZGK4?p=preview) is my example which I have already set maxWidth for the age column and it can not be resizable more than the maxWidth

Comment: I have the same issue, it's been already requested here: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/1614 Although you've asked this question three years ago, you may want to support the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This workaround by [ejbyne](https://github.com/ejbyne), helped me to achieve this in react.

https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/1614#issuecomment-1706809778

```
  const autoSizeColumns = () => {
    const allColumnIds: string[] = [];
    gridRef.current?.columnApi?.getColumns()?.forEach((column) => {
      allColumnIds.push(column.getId());
    });
    gridRef.current?.columnApi?.autoSizeColumns(allColumnIds, false);
    gridRef.current?.columnApi.getColumns()?.forEach((column) => {
      gridRef.current?.columnApi.autoSizeColumn(column.getId());
      if (column.getActualWidth() > MAX_COLUMN_WIDTH) {
        column.setActualWidth(MAX_COLUMN_WIDTH);
      }
    });
  };
```